# Facebook Sidebar/Tab Applications

Tags: facebook

Been searching the FB documentation to find an answer for this, but have been unsuccessful.

Is an application able to appear as a tab on a page/profile, and also in the sidebar of that same page/profile?

So the tab would show the full application details, but the sidebar would give a small breakdown.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah interesting, found [Developer Roadmap](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Developer_Roadmap) and basically lays out that what I am asking to do, won't be possible for much longer. Unfortunate, but I guess answers why I am finding it rather hard to do.

Answer (score 3):

Pages and profiles are different. You didn't used to be able to have a profile box and a tab for one application, but Facebook recently changed this. Probably because they stated the profile boxes are going away.

Adding an application as a tab on a Profile has always been a bit problematic and convoluted. The user had to click on the "+" tab, and your app may or may not appear under the list and/or come up in the search. However, 2 weeks ago Facebook announced support for an "add as tab" button.
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:add-profile-tab

Note that a user cannot add your application as a "profile box" until you have posted content to their profile (profile.setFBML) to be displayed in the box. The you can use the fb:add-section-button tag to display the "Add to Profile" button in your application. Box content is cached, so every time you want to update the content you need to post it to Facebook.

Adding an app as a tab to a Page has always been fairly easy. Go to the apps facebook page (not the app) and click on the "Add to My Page" link in the top left.

Comment: Ok thanks. Interesting regarding the profile section. Would you be able to expand upon this a bit more? For example. If I want to list 5 links in the page or profile's sidebar, do I need to post this to Facebook, to get it to update in the sidebar part of the application? Sorry if I am confused. This is the only part I'm unsure about in your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, for every user's profile box, you need to post the content you want displayed. If you change it, you need to repost. Facebook doesn't contact your servers when displaying profile content. Note the profile box has a max height, after which your content is cut off.

Answer (score 1):

Profile Boxes (and the corresponding Boxes Tab) [are gone](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Roadmap_Profile#Deprecated_Methods).

The replacement for both of these is [Application-Specific Tabs](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Tabbed_Profile#Application-Specific_Tabs). You are no longer able to push content directly to a user's profile.

Comment: They are not gone yet. Facebook is way behind on their roadmap.

Answer (score 0):

james, it is possible. just started developing fb apps three days ago. so far my app sits in my tabs and in my profile box, displaying different infos.

http://www.snipe.net/2008/09/planning-a-facebook-application/

try this.

Comment: Are you able to show me a screenshot of this in action on your profile? Thanks